# Jython - Extract information

Tags: jython

I try to programm in jython but I have some problems.

I would like to read information after the :

For the moment "Ext" only read the first line of the webpage and I don't know why.

This is the first problem.

Then I would like to do a while to read all the file.

When I did it, the while never finish.

how can I extract information after the :

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You should read next line in `while` loop, for now you read only one line! That is main problem that causes your while loop is infinite loop!
2. What library do you use to read HTTP response? Your code is without any `import`
3. Is it working code? I don't know `.Contains()` method. In Python/Jython there is `if ':' in Ext` to check if char or sting is in other string
4. You can split line like: `s1, s2 = Ext.split(':', 1)`, and then use `s2` variable: it contains text after first `:` , then you can `strip()` it to remove spaces or other white chars at both ends of the string